# Как сверстать макет попиксельно, если нужен background-image:cover

Tags: html, css

Макет width:1920px; картинка фона главной страницы width:1920px;

Условие: картинка должна заполнять весь фон всей ширины монитора, какой бы он ни был.

Ставим background-image:cover;

Вопрос:

Как быть с элементами, расположенными в слое над фоном, которые должны быть попиксельно сверстаны и привязаны попиксельно к элементам фоновой картинки? Если выполнить условие 100% заполняемости фона по ширине, то при изменении разрешения фон будет растягиваться и все элементы в слое сверху поплывут.
Есть какое-либо решение?